Connect Nodejs container to postgres container without docker-compose
I have 2 containers running in the same linux machine (and in the default bridge network), one for a Nodejs server (express) and the other for the official postgresql image, I want to connect from the Nodejs container to the postgresql container without using docker-compose.
This is how I started both containers:
Nodejs:
docker run -p 3001:3001 --env-file .env <image>

Postgres (here I mapped 5433 cause I also have postgres installed locally so 5432 is already taken):
docker run --name mydb -p 5433:5432 -dit postgres

This is the connection string I'm using in the nodejs server to try to connect to the postgres container:
postgresql://postgres:mypassword@<host>:5433/mydbname

Things I've already tried and didn't work:

add the host ip using --add-host=<host ip>:db and then use db as the host.
using the postgres container name mydb as the host.
using 127.0.0.1 or localhost as the host.


My mistake was that I was trying to connect to the postgres container using the mapped port 5433, it makes sense because port mapping after all refers to map containers ports to localhost ports, and in this case I'm not connecting from container to localhost but from container to another container so using the default postgresql port 5432 is ok, so the correct connection string will be:
postgresql://postgres:mypassword@mydbcontainer:5432/mydbname

Where mydbcontainer is the name of my postgres container, which is in the same network as the nodejs container.
Also this will not work with the default bridge network, so one needs to create a new network and attach the containers to it.
